# Cannot access keycloak UI using other hostname besides localhost on port: 8089, using other ports is Ok

Tags: docker, port, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to run keycloak in **8089** port,
if I start the docker container in that port I can access the keycloak ui from: **http://localhost:8089/**

but I cannot access it using the **keycloak** hostname (**http://keycloak:8089/**) or using http://**127.0.0.1**:8089.

If I use another port I am able to access the UI using keycloak hostname.

I have already configured the hosts file for the **keycloak** hostname, and ping to keycloak is okay.

I have tried:

- to reboot the PC
- reinstalled docker
- used rancher instead of docker
- used 8089:8089 as port for keycloak_demo
- reset **firewall** configurations

if I use 8089:8089 as port for keycloak_demo it will not run because keycloak on docker runs in 8080 port.

I do not have any other container running in that port.

Seams that something is wrong with that port.

Any help means a lot to me.

Docker-compose yml

```yml
    services:
      keycloak_demo:
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.5
        command: start-dev
        environment:
          KC_DB: postgres
          KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres_keycloak_demo
          KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
          KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
          KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
          KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
          KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
          KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
        ports:
          - "8089:8080"
        depends_on:
          postgres_keycloak_demo:
            condition: service_healthy
        networks:
          - keycloak_demo_dev_network
      postgres_keycloak_demo:
        image: postgres:14.2
        command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
        volumes:
          - pgdata_keycloak_demo:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
          POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
          POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        healthcheck:
          test: "exit 0"
        ports:
          - "5436:5432"
        networks:
          - keycloak_demo_dev_network
    volumes:
      pgdata_keycloak_demo:
    networks:
      keycloak_demo_dev_network:
        driver: bridge
```

failed to access keycloak from http://keycloak:8089/
[image]

Port 8089 in localhost **success**
[image: keycloak using localhost host name]

Using keycloak hostname and another port:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that port 8089 was being used by a source control (plastic SCM), and docker was not showing any warning about that

Comment: in such a scenario, `lsof -i :8089` on the machine where you try to start will mostly show if its been in use

Comment: is that command also for windows, it didn't run.

Comment: nope linux, since you did not mentioned the required information which can be read by [ask]

Comment: ah okay, i found a similar command for Windows and that showed me the ports that are being used